# Referencing to before site root

Tags: hyperlink, asp-classic

I have a few websites that are in a single folder for example:

en 
de
nl
fr...

in these folders are the websites.

What I want to do is add an images folder into here and have all of the sites referencing this images file. The reason for this is so when I add another image I only have to do it once not multiple times.

My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to reference to this file. I'm not sure if its possible becasue it is before the site roots.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, I do this all the time. Create a folder at that level for `images` then reference it as a Virtual Directory in each of the websites. Virtual Directories can reference any where as long as your anonymous account / app pool identity have access to read it.

Comment: Is there any chance you could send me a link to some sort of tutorial to do this. I'm at a lost end at how to actually do this

Comment: It depends on what version of IIS you are using if at all. For example if you are hosted by a third party you maybe using some sort of administrative web panel to configure your websites, these however can be lacking in functionality.

Comment: I'm using a VPS that runs IIS version 7 with full functionality to do whatever I want to on the server

Comment: In which case your websites will be setup inside IIS Manager, to add a virtual directory right click on the website from the list on the left and select `Add Virtual Directory...`. Fill in the alias and it's physical location and you are good to go. If you give your virtual directory an alias like `images` then when you create it in each of your websites you will access it like `/images`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do it as a virtual directory which you include in all your sites, but a stronger approach would be just to make it a site by iteself.   Chances are if you are using it for images, then its purpose is to serve static content.

What i would do is create a site named static.yoursite.com and in that site have a few folders (css img js).   Then when you need to load an image from any of your sites you would do it like this:

img src="//static.yoursite.com/img/global/background.png"  or
img src="//static.yoursite.com/img/de/welkome.gif"  or

Having it all in a separate site might make it easier to migrate to something like S3 or a real CDN like cloudfront in the future.  It will also make it super easy to set the proper expires headers and caching for static content.